# How do we get -840 reputation in a day?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Today, I noticed a -840 reputation in my reputation list. It lists the reputation change as below:

-75     04:25   removed     User was removed

-77     04:25   removed     User was removed

-228    04:24   removed     User was removed

-460    04:24   removed     User was removed

How can one remove his account from the SE? Does it cause my reputation to be removed?

Comment: As Ben notes, this will happen when a user account is deleted, either by request or due to a Terms of Service violation.

Comment: Wow! You must have been a real hit with those users, if they accounted for a fifth of your total reputation!

Comment: Wow that's some bad luck...

Comment: related: [erm… I lost 2,134 in reputation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/erm-i-lost-2-134-in-reputation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users can be deleted either because they're spammers (who usually don't vote), major abuse like sockpuppet voting (sockpuppets can be deleted) or at request. When a user is deleted, regardless of the reason, all of their votes are removed as well.

There's no indication of who was removed or why. But since there's 4 lines in the rep history it probably means 4 different users were removed. All their undone votes are rolled up into one item.

Comment: Maybe they were cleaning out their sock drawer that day. :)